# Which Java web framework closely resembles ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: java, web-frameworks

I need to port a ASP.NET MVC app to Java.  To make migration easier, I would like to use the most similar Java web framework to ASP.NET MVC.

I know basic Java web development [JSP/Servlets] but I don't any Java MVC framework.  What Java web framework would make my migration the easiest?

Any recommendations?

Comment: @Jeremy-Petzold, that's not very productive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered the [Play! Framework](http://www.playframework.org/)? Are other options are things like [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html). Play is pretty lightweight but gives you some features you might be accustomed to already.

Comment: I'd recommend Spring too. It's lightweit, mature, with good and full documentation, and with strong community. BTW [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) - a more recent documentation instead the upper link

Answer (score 2):

IMHO JSF is most similar to ASP.NET MVC.
Note that you did not ask about good Java MVC web framework.

Answer (score 1):

JSF is very similar to ASP.NET MVC. Originally JSF was build in a response to ASP.NET. Especially the parts dealing with controls (called components in JSF), view state, code behind (called backing beans in JSF) and master pages are fairly equal.

Standard ASP.NET MVC still uses web form pages with embedded C#, which is fairly similar as to how JSF used JSP with embedded Java.

JSF has deprecated this approach though some time ago and has made an all XML templating language (Facelets) the default. (there are alternative templating languages for ASP.NET which look quite like Facelets, but AFAIK those are not yet the default in ASP.NET).

Although it's of course subjective, JSF 2 is one of the best MVC frameworks in Java and one of the most popular as well. The Java web framework space is very fragmented though, so even the most popular framework in Java may only have some 16~20% of Java developers using it.

Comment: JSF is for sure the best MVC solution of all the mainstream solutions under the Java sun (Spring, Wicket, Tapestry, Struts ... ...). JSF could be even better had it incorporated ideas of HybridJava